# Express JS - 404 on static files

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I cannot seem to get express 3.x to server up static files in my public directory. They all request end with 404.

```
    var express = require('express')  
  , engine = require('ejs') 
  , app = express();


app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));   
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('test.ejs')
});


app.listen(3000);
```

My test.ejs is had references to the js files that look like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/testscene.js"></script>
```

I must be overlooking something simple. I have the following folder structure:

```
project
  -public
     -js
        testscene.js
  -views ]
```

Can someone tell me what I've missed?

**Update**

I actually created a new project and copied my script into this new project and it works?! 
I guess Ill just have to close this as some sort of localized weirdness. Thanks for all of your time.

Comment: Did you try calling it without the `app.configure`?  (basically, in top level)

Comment: I just did.. same difference.

Comment: Did you try /js/testscene.js as the url?

Comment: Yeah.. weird. I'm looking at other projects and this looks right.

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` is the directory where the current .js file resides. Your filesystem ascii art diagram omits this essential piece of the puzzle. If your first code snippet lives at `project/server.js`, for example, then that is correct. I think then loading `http://localhost:3000` in your browser should properly find the `js/testscene.js` file. However, using relative URIs is usually a bad idea unless you really are sure you want/need it, so for the sake of sanity, change that to be `src="/js/testscene.js"`.

Comment: The script that I am executing is at the root level. Meaning is is in the /project/main.js. I cannot find anything wrong with this.